The criterion about maximally localized Wannier function (WF)?
I heard that as the value of "num_iter(tag in wannier 90)" is higher, spread of Wannier function (=WF) is gradually lower in wannier 90. If so, is this procedure that minimize the spread of WF meaningful physically??
If I use a lot of num_iter for any projected orbital, the spread will be minimized. In this case, when different people draw the maximally minimized wannier functions for the same material, is there a standard by which they can be compared? Or is there a standard value for minimizing the spread of WF?
I would like to know the criteria for WF being minimized.

Read the papers. https://wannier.org/papers/ Also David Vanderbilt's (author of w90 and originator of the MLWF method) book has a good section https://doi.org/10.1017/9781316662205

Also, I think you are mixing up the disentanglment and minimization. Minimization work for isolated groups of bands and requires no info about projections. The projections are used to pick only a subset of bands out of a tangled group of them.
